# PHP simple login script (with if function)

Tags: php, authentication

I'm new to PHP and I just want a very simple insecure(for testing) login form.

I wrote this code:    but I do not get what I want, can you correct what I did wrong or what should I add, correct ...

> ```
>  <html>
> <body>
> <form>
> Username: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php $name ?>" ><br>
> Password: <input type"password" name="pass" value="<?php $pass ?>" ><br>
> <input type="submit">
> </form>
> <?php
> ```

```
if ($name == "root" && $pass == "laptop") {

    header("Location: /index.html");
    exit;

}




?>
```

Comment: So you have a form which isnt sending anywhere and you have another php script which is waiting for some data. Forms need to be told where to go and how to do it. Easiest thing to do is search for it online millions are available.

Comment: <form method="post" action="form.php">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP writes HTML which is then sent to the browser for rendering - once it has completed sending to the browser it exits. Hence your first mistake appears to be that you haven't understood the seperation of what happens at the server and what happens at the client.

Your next mistake is that your PHP operates on variables which happen to have the same names as form elements - but form vales are not automatically converted into PHP variables.

Your third error is that even when you've fixed the 2 previous problems your script won't work: any HTTP headers must be emitted before writing to the html body - so your redirect isn't going to work. Consider instead:

```
<?php
if ('root' == $_POST['name'] && 'laptop' == $pass) {
  header("Location: /index.html");
  exit;
}
?>
<html>
 <body>
  <form method='POST'>
   <?php print $_POST['name'] ? "Try again...." : "login..."; ?>
   <br /> 
   Username: <input type="text" name="name" 
        value="<?php print $_POST['name']; ?>" ><br />
   Password: <input type"password" name="pass" 
         value="<?php print $_POST['pass'] ?>" ><br />
   <input type="submit">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make two files - one with html and the other one with php function.
in html add to form action and method

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="php_file_name.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="name" value="" ><br>
Password: <input type"password" name="pass" value="" ><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and put in php_file_name.php this php code that you wrote, knowing that you're using POST method, that is:

```
<?php
    if ($_POST[name] == "root" && $_POST[pass] == "laptop") {
        header("Location: /index.html");
        exit;
    }
```

It should work then. Of course you can choose other name of php_file_name.php but with changing it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The php code you inserted into the form has no function, it does nothing. I edited your form, so that it sends data to the same page. You can then do:

`$name = $_POST['name'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];`

Your old code comes after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in the same file index.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
echo 'you submitted name='.$_POST['name'].' And password='.$_POST['pass'].'<br /><br />';
}

echo '<form method="post">
Name <input name="name" type="text" /><br />
Pass <input name="pass" type="password" /><br />
<input name"submit" type="submit" />
</form>';
?>
```